# I have an array on strings in php. I want to replace all occurrences of those strings with another string within a block of text

Tags: php, replace

I have an array that contains several domain names. I need to replace those domains inside blocks of text (forum posts) with another string, if any of them actually appear inside that forum post.

Whats the best way of doing that? I can't alter the array that contains a list of domains it would search for. Its stored as follows:

```
$domain_list = array("domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `str_replace` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Combined with a foreach loop.

Comment: @Blair, you don't need a loop, since `str_replace` accepts arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$modified_haystack = str_replace($domain_list, $repl, $haystack);
```

`$repl` is the replacement text, `$haystack` is the text to search.